# Docker - Creating base image with RHEL iso

Tags: image, docker, rhel

I am trying to use a RHEL image for my project. Is there a way to create a base image with my RHEL 6's iso file? I am not using Fedora as it is beneficial for my project to use the RHEL distribution instead.

Comment: Have a look at this post https://access.redhat.com/discussions/734363 Also you many want to use CentOS 6 image - https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/centos/

Comment: Thanks! I've found the answer as well! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/TGvzjR4afzI

Comment: Good to know that :-)

Comment: @Han - You should make the contents of that URL an actual answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fair bit of control, you may want to look into the script in the Docker [contrib repository](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/contrib) on Github.

[One of them](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh) is for "yum" based images, Centos in this case, but there's no reason it shouldn't work for RHEL.

It bootstraps itself through a series of YUM installs. If you look at the usage:

```
OPTIONS:
-p "<packages>"  The list of packages to install in the container.
               The default is blank.
-g "<groups>"    The groups of packages to install in the container.
               The default is "Core".
-y <yumconf>     The path to the yum config to install packages from. The
               default is /etc/yum.conf for Centos/RHEL and /etc/dnf/dnf.conf for Fedora
```

you can see that you can provide your own yum.conf, which you can set to use your ISO as source.