# Is it possible to create a docker image from Ubuntu ISO on Windows offline?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker

I have Docker and Ubuntu ISO on my PC but cannot access Docker hub.

Is it possible to create a docker image from Ubuntu ISO on Windows offline ?

Comment: try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518646/docker-creating-base-image-with-rhel-iso
and this http://serverfault.com/questions/739981/how-to-create-a-docker-image-by-downloading-an-iso-using-packer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import an archive representing that ubuntu image onto your local docker registry with [`docker save`/`docker load`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932570/6309).

If you have one computer having access to Docker hub, pull and then save the Ubuntu image as one archive file, copy it onto an USB key and then on your PC. Load it and you will be able to build your own image `FROM ubuntu`.